# No se muestra el contenido al refrescar una página con pushState en HTM5

Tags: php, javascript, html5, spa

Estoy haciendo uso del **History API** (con `pushState`) para manipular mi contenido en una sola página. La página posee un campo de búsqueda que va mostrando una lista de términos a medida que coinciden los caracteres ingresados por el usuario. Luego al presionar la tecla enter o hacer clic en el botón buscar se ve el contenido para ese término buscado (todo siempre en la misma página y haciendo uso de **AJAX** para no recargar toda la página), quedando la URL por ejemplo `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Inteligencia_artificial` para el caso que la búsqueda sea "Inteligencia artificial", si ingresa de nuevo otro término por ejemplo "Computadora" ahora la URL quedaría `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` y si presiona para atrás en el navegador la misma vuelve a cambiar a `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Inteligencia_artificial` haciendo uso de `popState`.

Ahora sólo me falta una cosa: Que al actualizar la página se muestre el contenido que coincide con la URL. Es que si la URL dice `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` y presiono el botón de actualizar no hace nada y me pone el error "Objeto no localizado", como un 404 (página no encontrada). Y si allí mismo quiero ir para atrás, me pasa lo mismo, ya no puedo ver el contenido anterior. Estoy trabajando localmente y me falta solucionar esto para poder subirlo al servidor.
Les paso mi código de JavaScript (utilizando JQuery) que está en mi index:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                            
$(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
    var state = e.originalEvent.state;
    if (state !== null) {
        state=state.split("_").join(" ");
        document.title = state+" - Mi sitio";
        showHint(state);
    }else{$("#Contenido").empty();
         }  
});

$('#boton').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var Term = document.getElementById("Termino").value;
   if (Term !== '') {
       document.title = Term+" - Mi sitio";
       Term=Term.split(" ").join("_");
        showHint(Term);
        history.pushState(Term,Term+" - Mi sitio",Term);
        e.preventDefault();
   }
});

$("#Termino").keypress(function(e){
if(e==13||e.which==13){
    e.preventDefault();
    var d=document.getElementById("Termino").value;
    if(d!==''){
        document.title = d+" - Mi sitio";
        d=d.split(" ").join("_");
        showHint(d);
        history.pushState(d,d+" - Mi sitio",d);
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#radio").buttonset({disabled:null});
        return false;
    }
}});
 $(document).on('click', '#GloIT', function (e) {    
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this),
     def = $this.attr("href"); 
     if(def!==''){
        def=def.split("_").join(" ");
        document.title = def+" - Mi sitio";
        showHint(def);
        def=def.split(" ").join("_");
        history.pushState(def,def+" - Mi sitio",def);
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#radio").buttonset({disabled:null});
        return false;
      }
   });
 });
```

Aquí hay varios eventos (los dos que se generan por *clic* y el del *enter*) y que básicamente hacen lo mismo, eso está funcionando bien. Todos llaman a la función *showHint(Termino a buscar)* que es la que trabaja con **AJAX** y después mediante **PHP** muestra el contenido. También al principio está el código para el *popstate*. Todo esto funciona perfecto, el problema está al refrescar la página, como ya comente al principio. Intente poner la función *showHint()* suelto dentro de `$(document).ready(function () {` pero nunca entra allí, también intente poner código dentro de la función `function load_content(){` pero nada de nada.

Lo que me doy cuenta es que si yo por ejemplo recargo la página como `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/` si entra a `$(document).ready(function () {` pero si recargo la página `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` no entra a `$(document).ready(function () {`.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer lo de refrescar?

Answer (score 4):

La solución no depende tu código, sino del servidor web. Trato de explicarlo:

Para que una SPA (Single Page Application, Aplicación de una sola página) pueda refrescarse de ese modo lo que hay que hacer es deshabilitar la respuesta 404 de tu servidor.

Supongamos que:

1. Tu aplicación web carga todo (y por tanto tiene su *raíz* en `http://localhost/`).
2. El usuario navega, pasando de la raíz (`/`) a otra *página* (`/ApiHistory`). Realmente no se ha hecho una petición al servidor, sino que tu aplicación cambia la URL del navegador.
3. El usuario refresca la aplicación o (un escenario habitual) va directamente a esta dirección porque la tiene en sus *Favoritos*.
4. El servidor recibe la petición y no encuentra esa página.

Estamos en el punto interesante: el servidor puede...

- Responder con un HTTP status 404: El navegador mostrará una página de error con un mensaje, que puede ser la respuesta del navegador o una página propia (suele depender del tamaño de la respuesta).
- Redirigir a otra página: Es muy típico tener una página que muestre el 404 de un modo *más bonito* y personalizado, como hace por ejemplo [StackOverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/noexiste).

Ahora bien, si la página de error la defines como la página inicial de tu aplicación (`/`), ¿qué ocurre? Pues que tu página se carga con la URL `http://localhost/ApiHistory`. Una vez que tu aplicación se ha inicializado no tiene más que mirar la URL y mostrar la página correspondiente.

Es por esto que los frameworks como React o Angular suelen usar un *router* que se encarga de gestionar, como una *máquina de estados*, qué URL es la actual y qué se tiene que mostrar en esa URL.

Por tanto, si usas Apache, o Nginx o cualquier otro servidor web, tendrás que mirar la documentación correspondiente y configurar la gestión del error 404 para que se adecue a lo que necesitas.

En Nginx sería añadir a la configuración algo como

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

En Apache sería (creo) añadir algo como

```
ErrorDocument 404 /ApiHistory/
```

en tu fichero .htaccess

Comment: estaba probando lo de _.htaccess_ de forma local. Donde puse: `ErrorDocument 404 /GloMovil/ApiHistory/` ahora no me muestra el mensaje de "Objeto no localizado" pero tampoco me muestra el contenido que está en la URL `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora`. Utilizando el navegador Chrome para ver los eventos en JavaScript, pasa lo mismo, nunca entra al `$(document).ready(function (){//}` es más ni siquiera se ve el index.php desde el Network que proporciona la consola del Chrome (por eso nunca entra). ¿se puede probar esto localmente?

Comment: Ahora mi página de inicio está en `ApiHistory` y estoy haciendo en .htaccess `ErrorDocument 404 /ApiHistory/` pero no entra nunca al `index.php` cuando se refresca la página. También he probado con `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` pero la URL se me va a `http://localhost:81/dashboard/` o sea mucho más atrás. 
En definitiva, mi URL que quiero refrescar es `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` para luego poder ir a buscar el contenido que trae el término "Computadora". ¿Quizás no se pueda hacer localmente?

Comment: No me resultó, fue lo mismo que cuando puse `/ApiHistory/`. Lo que si está funcionando es que si voy para atrás o para adelante en el navegador el contenido lo pone, por más que antes al refrescar no lo muestre. Por ejemplo, hago una búsqueda y la URL queda `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/RAM` luego pongo "Computadora" y queda  `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` después refresco la página (no me muestra nada), pero si voy para atrás me muestra el contenido de "RAM" y si hago para adelante el de "Computadora".

Comment: Bueno al final lo pude solucionar. La línea en el archivo _.htaccess_ quedo así `ErrorDocument 404 /ApiHistory/` y era un tema de ubicación del código de JavaScript, lo puse al principio y funciona al refrescar la página, al menos de forma local. No sé que pasará cuando lo suba. Otra duda, todo esto anda bien si trabajo siempre en la misma página, pero que pasa si la URL viene de afuera (o sea de otro sitio, buscadores, etc.), ¿debería funcionar?

Comment: Tu servidor sólo recibirá una petición `HTTP GET <url>` desde un cliente (normalmente un navegador), da igual si esa URL la escribieron en la barra de direcciones o si estaba en un link en otra página. Edito la respuesta ahora que sabemos exactamente cómo funciona :)

Comment: Pasa que ahora localmente lo estoy probando a full para después subirlo y veo que hay cosas que no funcionan, si yo por ejemplo tengo la URL `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/RAM` y voy a editar la URL desde el navegador y escribo por ejemplo `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` y refresco la página, **no me muestra nada** ¿Eso está bien que pase? Por eso no sé si va a funcionar si el link viene de otro sitio/lugar. 
Distinto es, si busco algo internamente en el sitio y luego actualizo la página, allí si me muestra el contenido.

Comment: Cuando puse *(creo)* en la respuesta es porque **nunca** he trabajado con Apache, sino con Nginx, así que estoy tan perdido como tú en el tema de configurarlo. Sé que me funciona perfectamente en mi portal en producción, que usa la misma técnica.

Comment: Entiendo, ahora es normal que el contenido no se vea desde código. O sea si hago **Ctrl+u** para ver el código de la página no me sale el contenido que si estoy viendo en la página. ¿Será porque es AJAX y es algo normal al ser algo dinámico?

Comment: Dices que te funciona perfectamente en tu portal y que usas la misma técnica. ¿O sea que haces uso del **API History** y todos los links te funcionan? Porque a mi, en la misma página todo funciona perfecto, pero si hago click en un enlace que viene desde otro lugar (por ejemplo otra página de mi sitio) no funciona, no me muestra nada. Todo esto lo estoy probando de manera local y con el agregado de `ErrorDocument 404 /ApiHistory/`. Qué raro que a ti te funcione, más allá de Apache ¿Será otra línea que deba agregar al archivo **.htaccess**? No encuentro mucha info sobre esto.

Comment: Yo trabajo con Angular, que mediante su componente *Router* gestiona todo por mi. Es decir, no me peleo manualmente con el API, pero sé que Angular lo hace. Cuando dices que no muestra nada... ¿qué te sale en la consola?

Comment: O sea yo estoy en la página interna de mi sitio `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/EfemeridesIT.php` que muestra contenido y dentro de ese contenido hay diferentes links que al clickear (por ejemplo _Computadora_) me llevan a la página principal para el ejemplo sería `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora` . Pero no me muestra nada, solo el index sin el contenido de _Computadora_ . En definitiva me muestra la página como si entrara la primera vez, pero la URL se muestra como `http://localhost:81/ApiHistory/Computadora`.

Comment: Entonces el problema es que tu aplicación no lee la URL para saber qué tiene que hacer y mostrar, asume que está en la URL inicial. Debes tener en algún lado que se lea de `window.location.pathname` (por ejemplo) dónde estás para saber qué mostrar

Comment: Yo tengo cargado lo siguiente al inicio de mi script:
`$().ready(function(){
 var state = history.state;
 if (state !== null) {
  state=state.split(" ").join("_");
  showHint(state);
  history.pushState(state,state+" - Mi sitio", state);
  }`
Y que funciona si se refresca la página, pero no si viene externamente. El contenido lo muestro desde la función `showHint(link a buscar) `.

Comment: No quería agregar más script a mi sitio, pero bueno, si con Angular se soluciona voy a tener que hacerlo. Sólo pondría la parte que hace uso del _Router_ ¿Cuál sería ese código que debo agregar? Además de tener que poner en el _<head>_ la línea `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>` o algo aprecido.

Comment: No intentes añadir Angular a un proyecto a medias... Simplemente lee la URL actual y simula que has navegado hasta ahí

Comment: Te puedo pasar la URL por aca (ya he subido para probarlo en Internet) para que veas como queda y lo puedas ir viendo. No importaría que este mal online por ahora (con esos detalles que me faltan), me importa más el poder solucionarlo y quizás viéndolo me puedes ayudar. No sé si te dejan poner la URL aca. De todas formas me dices.

Comment: pásate por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de SOes

Comment: el `ErrorDocument 404 /ApiHistory/` va el archivo HTML directo es algo como `ErrorDocument 404 /ApiHistory/error404.html`

Answer (score 1):

Para darle un cierre a este hilo, al final encontré la solución cuando se refresca la página. Tuve que agregar las siguientes líneas al archivo **.htaccess** de Apache:
    `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]`